# A spell or curse to make enemies take damage from healing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm looking to turn my enemies healing against them as harm.

Is there a spell or a curse that causes positive energy to do damage instead of healing as if they were undead without actually making them undead?

Comment: There is a spell in DnD 3.5 which does this - but you probably don't use 3.5 material in your game, do you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a direct option for the inverse, forcing an undead to have positive energy affinity, with [Undeath Inversion](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Undeath%20Inversion) (most non-psychic casters level 4)

Getting a punish for an opponent's positive energy is harder. Indirectly, you can benefit from their spells with [Healing Thief](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Healing%20Thief) (level 1 for Mesmerist, 3 for other psychic and arcane) or debuff the healer with [Teratoid Caress](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Teratoid%20Caress) (cleric 3, note that it's [evil] and from a niche source)

The most fitting option takes a specific build. The [Oracle's Burden](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Oracle%27s%20Burden) spell (level 2) applies the downside of the user's Oracle Curse. The Lich and Vampirism curses apply negative energy affinity as their 1st-level effect, so Oracle's Curse would cause the target to take damage from positive energy. (I would probably rule that they don't get to heal from negative energy either, as that's the 1st-level upside of those curses and Oracle's Burden doesn't copy the upsides)

I didn't check much more than searching the one-line spell descriptions for "positive", "negative", and "heal", so there may be more options using other methods.